# SQL repetitive code in where clause, how to insert the whole where into variable

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

### I write a lot of queries with the same WHERE clause. I wish i could create a variable to insert each time for a query.
My query:

```
select distinct order_external_status
from analytics.dwh_orders_details dod
**where dod.merchant_id = 7797
and order_type = 'pre_live'
and order_date >= '2019-09-10' and order_date <= '2019-09-24';**
```

---

### Next query with the same WHERE:

```
select dod.order_id,
oc.*
from analytics.dwh_orders_details dod
left join analytics.dwh_oc_all_details oc
on dod.order_id = oc.order_id
**where dod.merchant_id = 7797
  and order_type = 'pre_live'
  and order_date >= '2019-09-10' and order_date <= '2019-09-24';**
```

---

Can have 10 to 15 queries like that in a day. It will be nice if i could put where clause in a variable and just write it once. For now we use Redshift, we will move to Snowflake soon, if it matters.
DBs not allow to create views or temp tables...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view and use the view in your queries:

```
create view v_myview as 
    select dod.*
    from analytics.dwh_orders_details dod 
    where dod.merchant_id = 7797 and
          dod.order_type = 'pre_live' and
          dod.order_date >= '2019-09-10' and
          dod.order_date <= '2019-09-24';
```

Comment: Nice   I prefer temp table but i like the way! Thanks

Comment: Hi, DB not allow to create views or temp tables, work on snowflake

Comment: Interesting - is it that the DBA is preventing the use of views, temp tables or transient tables?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-introduction.html - Table functions also look a useful feature  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table.html